# To add new value in every element in list in R?

Tags: r, list

here is `list1`, only tow elements--"`name`" and "`age`" in it,there are two value in every element ,now i want to add new value in every element,

```
list1<-list(name=c("bob","john"),age=c(15,17))
list1
$name
[1] "bob"  "john"

$age
[1] 15 17
list1[[1]][3]<-"herry"
list1[[2]][3]<-17
list1
$name
[1] "bob"   "john"  "herry"

$age
[1] 15 17 17
```

is there more simple way to do ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solution works for lists of any length:

```
values <- list("herry", 17) # a list of the new values
list1 <- mapply(append, list1, values, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)


# $name
# [1] "bob"   "john"  "herry"

# $age
# [1] 15 17 17
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the solution given by @Sven Hohenstein is provided by the rlist library. It's not better but a little more intuitive to read. If the key is the same, it's a bit easier to program IMHO.

`library(rlist)
list1 <- list.append(list1, key=value)`

Note that the key is written without quotes. So in your example, it would be:

`library(rlist)
list1 <- list.append(list1, henry=17)`

Answer (score -1):

It depends a bit on what you want to do. If you want to add a different value to each element in the list, I think the easiest way is:

```
Vec <- c("herry",17,...)
i=0 
list1 <- lapply(list1, function(x) {i=i+1 ; append(x,Vec[i])})
```

If every vector in your list has the same length, then there's some shortcuts you can use too.
If you want to add the same value to every element in the list:

```
list1 <- lapply(list1, function(x) append(x, "NewEl"))
```